# Kali Linux not updating?

Tags: kali-linux, upgrade

I just now installed kali linux and tried to update using  `apt-get update` but nothing really happens

this is my source list

```
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2018.1 _Kali-rolling_ -
 Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20180126-21:23]/ kali-last-snapshot contrib 
main non-free

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
# deb-src
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing really happens"?  Literally nothing happens or nothing you deem worthy of mentioning happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your sources.list as follows:

```
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2018.1 _Kali-rolling_ -
#Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20180126-21:23]/ kali-last-snapshot contrib 
#main non-free

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
# deb-src
```

Or simply run:

```
echo deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You should comment the second and the 3rd lines in your `sources.list`.

See [The Kali Rolling Repository](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)

Comment: what does this # do in source list , is it  mean no-commenting the line

Comment: @Karamzov It means commenting out the line so it won't be treated.  Please don't take offense, but if you have to ask this kind of questions you should study some basic Linux documentation and start from a Linux distro that's more suitable fro neophytes, not Kali.

Comment: @dr01  , i  got it now and thanks for being helpful  unlike others who are sitting on an assumed horse

Comment: @dr01 , i am fine with kali at the moment

Comment: If you have to ask these kind of questions it does not seem you are fine with Kali *at all*. Kali as a general distribution is not so well cared of,  and badly configured, and many more pitfalls over time will happen that do not appear on regular distros. I just prefer to work with regular distros, than  losing my time with distros damaged by design, and that my reflect in the questions I chose to pick up, and invest and donate my *free* time answering. I suspect I am not alone in that.